# How to use a graphical interface for remote CentOS 6 server via ssh?

Tags: centos, ssh, gui

I am given a project that needs to be done in CentOS. So I rented a CentOS 6 droplet on digitalocean.com. I created a user for myself.

Everything was going easy until I got to install a huge program called Xilinx ISE.

Here is the documentation:

[image]

[image]

Till here it was so smooth, I installed everything so far. But ISE is more complicated than I thought.

[image]

[image]

So I think I need to install a graphical interface to the droplet and another package to communicate through ssh terminal somehow. (I am using `putty`). I've been searching for ways to do it but I really could not. So, could you suggest me something here? Any easy way to install this huge software on to centOS 6?

Note: Remember I am at remote desktop reaching to remote server through SSH(PuttY)

Comment: Xming (for remote X11 over ssh) or using VNC (again over ssh) are two approaches.

Comment: Which one is easier you think?

Comment: Xming is probably easier to get working, though sucks if the connection is slow (e.g. only for local area network use), or if the connection drops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ssh X11 forwarding:

```
ssh -X user@host
```

Then you can start `xterm` or any x11 application.